# Any Solutions To Viva Deadlocks?

Tags: phd, defense

The field: humanities - combining historical research done via study of old manuscripts written in late middle ages versions of a now uncommon European language.

The situation: a previously stellar student denied a doctorate at viva in a major world university.

The outcome: the student returns to their home state, acquires a modest teaching position in their field at a small university via their MA and a research fellowship prior to the PhD programme, succeeds in teaching and research, later moves to a bigger university and about 10 years after the viva failure is awarded a doctorate (from the same university that denied it to her) on the basis of quality published work in the interim period.

The question: how could we avoid a student not being awarded their doctorate where there is a conflict of judgement between an external examiner and the student (plus their supervisor)?

---

A "viva" is, in essence an exam based on a dissertation with a number of people able to judge the result, perhaps with a vote. It is called a "defense" in some places. Examiners in a viva can challenge the candidate and the dissertation in some places.

A "deadlock" is a disagreement between examiners that results in strong differences of opinion that don't make it clear, necessarily, whether the student should "pass" or not.

Comment: This question seems incredibly vague to me: what's a "viva deadlock", because it isn't mentioned in the question body. Why should these be avoided in general, rather than in this particular case? Who is to say that anything actually went *wrong* here?

Comment: Clearly the student - and one would expect also their supervisor for the previous 3 years - considered a thesis to be adequate but the external examiner did not. Both need to agree before the thesis is sent to the university formally for award of doctorate. Hence the deadlock.

Comment: "Deadlock" implies there is no way to resolve the situation. In your "major world university" (please name a system), the external examiner can just veto a doctorate and sucks for everyone, no redoes?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him  Seemingly not in a way that the student and supervisor would agree to.

Comment: @Trunk "Clearly the student - and one would expect also their supervisor for the previous 3 years - considered a thesis to be adequate but the external examiner did not" That's not clear to me at all, because you haven't explained this at all. It also sounds like the deadlock was resolved once the student completed further work. How can we objectively determine here whether the external examiner had a reasonable complaint about the thesis originally submitted?

Comment: No. It was not resolved at all. The PhD awarded 10 years later would not have been allowed to concern the same topic as the thesis submitted and rejected due to the 2-6 years time limit.

Comment: I understand you are trying to keep things general, but this question is lacking detail. For example, everything that happened to the student after being denied the viva doesn't seem relevant to the actual question. Furthermore, you'll have to state in which country the viva was denied, as the answer will depend on the system.

Comment: The question seems to reduce to something analogous to: "if 70% is the cutoff for passing, how do we avoid failing students who scored less than 70%"?

Comment: @cag51. That is what I think as well

Comment: @cag51  That is a ridiculous comment. If there was a clear conflict between supervisor and external examiner on something the thesis lacked, then that doesn't necessarily mean that it is a case of a sore-loser student wanting to redraw the boundary lines.

Comment: @Trunk How is it ridiculous? cag51's comment is exactly how I'm reading this, how Pikachu is reading it - if you want us to think differently, it seems you'd need to present it differently. Why would there ever need to be an external examiner if the assumption was that their opinion of a thesis is invalid?

Comment: @Bryan Krause  I have no issue on having EEs or them having a right to order rewrites to parts of a thesis, supplementary data addition to support assertions, even a veto where EE judges it to be wholly unsalvageable. But where something - perhaps essential to the thesis in the supervisor's and student's views - is ordered removed from a thesis, you have a scenario of peer conflict. I can't see how an EE can *fairly* write off 3 years work.

Comment: @Bryan Krause   And it does happen that some EEs may be personally offensive based on their reaction to the candidate, their gender, dress, accent, manner, tone of voice, perceived ethnicity/religion, etc. There is a limit to what the supervisor may do about this on the day, although a  supervisor ought to consider this when selecting the EE with the candidate.

Comment: @Trunk I missed in your question the part where an external examiner has ordered something removed from a thesis because of a personal bias they hold. By the same token, it shouldn't matter how precious these elements are to the supervisor or student, but rather whether they are scientifically/academically rigorous. The EE isn't writing off 3 years of work, they're judging that the work done is not sufficient to have earned a PhD; the work is still there.

Comment: @Trunk I also missed in your question the part where the EE is preventing a candidate from earning a PhD due to the candidate's gender, dress, accent, etc.

Comment: @Bryan K  It seems you missed the subjunctive connotation of "where" and "it happens that". Or else you miss the need to protect against not infrequent possibilities occurring in exchanges during vivas when devising viva rules. I no more than you do not know what actually happened during the viva in question. But I know the candidate involved was a top-rank student and very orthodox to boot. Hence my willingness to question this whole PhD denial.

Comment: @Trunk You'll get a better response if you ask the question you want to ask rather than loosely alluding to it. Your first version of the question did not even mention an external examiner. Your current version mentions them only in that there is an unspecified "conflict in judgment" between external examiner and the student/parenthetically their advisor; presumably such a conflict exists every time an external examiner says "no". Instead, it seems you want to ask about the case where an external examiner's ruling is in some way unjustified. If that's what you want to ask about, ask it.

Comment: @Bryan K But here again "unjustified" is a debatable term depending on which side of the disagreement that you are on. The question here really is when there is serious conflict between supervisor and EE on the acceptability of a thesis - something too essentially field-based for others present in the viva to be able to offer any useful opinion - then how can we avoid having the candidate's work being left in limbo thereafter ? Could we have an application to the university authorities for a "second opinion" mechanism in such cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is an easy solution, but you have to think hard (hard) about whether you want to implement it or not.

You have a rule, whether you think of it that way or not, that deadlocks are not resolved in favor of the student. You could change that rule. You'd have to think hard (hard) about what a different (better?) rule might be. The most generous rule would be always in the student's favor. Another might be in favor of the supervisor's vote. Another might be to appoint someone else to resolve the deadlock. Others are possible.

Before choosing a policy, however, look at your history and decide what the impact would have been (likely to have been) with a different rule. If it is rare then it is probably easier to find something than if it is common.

Comment: It's not a change of rules as such but couldn't a "second opinion" be allowed **in cases where the student's supervisor is adamant on the quality of the thesis as is** ? As it happens, I'm reading Oppenheimer's bio at present and therein it says that de Broglie's PhD might not have been granted at all had it not been sent to Einstein and he been positive towards it. Experts can sharply disagree in academia as elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that could work, but it needs to be a policy (i.e. rules).